# Mongo aggregation of ISODate into 45 minute chunks

Tags: mongodb

I have a series of documents that have an ISODate object. I'm trying to group those into 45 minute blocks. So minutes 0-45 would be one group and minute 45-next min 30 would be another.

My first idea was to divide the time but since these aren't unix timestamps I've been unable to do math with the ISODate. My second idea was to $project out the hour, minute, days, etc, but realized it will be challenging to group when the timeblock span two separate days.

```
# This doesn't work since you cant do the division.
query = [
    { 
        "$match": {
            '_id.t': { 
                '$gte': new Date(2014, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                '$lte': new Date(2014, 6, 1, 1, 0, 0) 
            }
        }
    },

    {
        "$project": {
            "milliseconds": { '$millisecond': '$_id.t' }
        }
    },

    {

        "$project": {
            "timeblock": { 
                "$divide": [
                    '$milliseconds', 900000
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    {
        "$group": { "_id": { "timeblock": "$timeblock" } }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think following can solve the question:

```
var baseDate = new Date(2014, 09, 17, 14, 25, 0);  // any value as you want
var startDate = new Date(2014, 09, 17, 14, 25, 0);
var endDate = new Date(2014, 09, 20, 14, 25, 0);
var divisor = 45 * 60 * 1000; // milliseconds of 45 minutes

db.cc.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        date : {
            $gte : startDate,
            $lt : endDate
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            $subtract : [ "$date", {
                $mod : [ {
                    $subtract : [ "$date", baseDate ]
                }, divisor ]
            } ]
        },
        dates : {
            $push : "$date"
        }
    }
} ]).pretty();
```

Explanation for grouping:

```
_id : {
    $subtract : [ "$date", {                    /* start date of each block */
        $mod : [ {                              /* remainder */
            $subtract : [ "$date", baseDate ]   /* offset */
        }, divisor ]
    } ]
},
```

Comment: Cool approach.  I didn't realize you could use the arithmetic operators on a mix of dates and numbers like that.

Comment: This is a prime example for the aggregation framework's capabilities. Very nice.