# Offset value before grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, unix-timestamp, timezone-offset

I have a couple of items of which one field is a UTC-based unix timestamp multiplied by 1000 in order to include milliseconds while keeping it a `long` (integer) value.

```
{ 
    "title" : "Merkel 'explains' refugee convention to Trump in phone call", 
    "iso" : "2017-01-31T04:03:53.807+0000", 
    "id" : NumberLong(1485835433807)
}
{ 
    "title" : "NASA to Explore an Asteroid Containing Enough Mineral Wealth to Collapse the World Economy", 
    "iso" : "2017-01-30T23:20:27.327+0000", 
    "id" : NumberLong(1485818427327)
}
{ 
    "title" : "IMGKit: Python library of HTML to IMG wrapper", 
    "iso" : "2017-01-30T23:15:39.488+0000", 
    "id" : NumberLong(1485818139488)
}
```

the `iso` field is just a text string to ease debugging, it has no other purpose.

I intend to use the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550803/277267 to resample the items, to create a summary of items per day, initially just a count if items per day.

The problem is that the timestamp (the `"id"` field) can't really be used to archieve this, because of the UTC offset. Depending on the location of the user (or the local insertion time, ie 00:30 monday local time vs 23:30 sunday UTC time, if the timezone is +1h) an item would belong either to one day or the other, so the field lacks this information.

Assuming I just want to add an offset to the `"id"` field, ie by 3600000, which is one hour expressed in milliseconds, before starting to resample the data based on the `"id"` field, how can I archieve this in the aggregation pipeline?

Is there a way to have a first stage which takes the `"id"` field value, add 3600000 to that value and store it into an `"id_offsetted"` field, on which I can then execute the next stages?

Comment: I'm not following your reasoning behind storing date as a numberlong, because the date object is precise enough to include milliseconds.

Comment: This is to solve performance issues on the clients (Java and JavaScript). I'm dealing with 10's of 1000's of items per fetch, seconds of wait-time for the user do matter. Also, the `"id"` field is a unique hashable, sortable and indexable key (on a per-user basis)

Comment: Most likely your reason for loading 10,000 + documents into memory isn't a good one. The work that your Java / JavaScript is trying to do with those records should be done in the queries.

Comment: @ChadHedgcock I agree. This will change in the future.

Comment: @ChadHedgcock Funny thing: this aggregating and assigning an item to a day is in preparation for starting to serve chunks of items based on the day they belong to. AFAIK using a date object doesn't solve the tz-offset issue as these are also stored in UTC. As I'm having a problem with the aggregation (can't round numbers trivially), I believe that I'll best serve two additional days, one before the lower range, and one after the upper one, and let the client filter them out. Not sure though, yet.

Comment: So the aggregation is to build a list of populated days with an item count in it in order to give the UI the ability to show a visual summary of the days without having to fetch all the data.

Comment: Probaly it's the best to add another int field representing the day the item got inserted, in local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version before 3.4

```
   {$project: { 
        "title" :  1, 
        "iso" : 1
        "id" : 1,
        "id_offsetted" : {$add: ["$id", 3600000]}   
    } }
```

Version 3.4 onwards

```
 {$addFields: {
        "id_offsetted" : {$add: ["$id", 3600000]}   
    } }
```